# How to make a camera/cframe that can update frame in lua/roblox?

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm making a window view on my Roblox flight simulator project. I asked ChatGPT how to do it, and the code given wasn't working, so i decided to make it myself. I know the cframe basics like cameratype = scriptable and custom one.

I want to make an UI button which will toggle and switch player camera to part's cframe. ChatGPT prompted me a code using RenderStepped service. It actually worked and updates the frame pretty smooth but somehow, I couldn't turn it off and the UI button isn't working.